# PHP obfuscation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm completely new to PHP, and have just started with Wordpress. I need to customise a plugin (Register Plus Redux), but it appears to have been deliberately obfuscated.

It doesn't use DOS, Unix, or Apple line-end conventions, and simply ends all lines with a CR. emacs can make some sense of it, but tools like grep can't - lots of lines just over-write each other. Many lines are 250 or 350 characters long. It does contain a few low-quality comments.

This is all pretty irritating, since the author doesn't appear to sell the code, and the code is GPLv2 licensed, and he based it on somebody else's work anyway. Still, that's beside the point.

Anyone know of a tool that actually does this, or can (partially, anyway) undo this? I guess the answer has to be no - the source still has some comments in it, so this is presumably a very half-hearted manual obfuscation. Still, thought I'd ask.

Is this common? I'm getting a bad feeling about PHP. Some of the code I've seen just looks like it was written by amateurs.

*EDIT*

One of the comments asked me to post an example. I can't really do that, but here's what I've tried. If I extract `rpr-login.php` from the original zip file, on Windows, then Notepad shows only junk, but Wordpad does show line breaks at the CRs, so it's readable. I don't really use Windows so can't comment on what a proper editor would show. On Linux, xemacs turns the CRs into NLs, so it's readable. It's also readable on vi. 'less' shows junk with lots of CR characters, 'grep' is unusable, and so on. I can do a trivial fix on Linux with a Perl script to convert CR to NL, but I think it would be pointless, given that the code would still have many 300-character lines. I agree with williamt's red flag comment.

Comment: Welcome to the club. You are correct, a lot of the code you will see was written by amateurs.

Comment: yes it's pretty common for people who want to earn stuff and people who want to do shady things hidden as cool stuff. have you tried search php deobfuscator on google?

Comment: There is no way you can de-obfuscated, but you can make it slightly more beautifier. Google "php beautifier". There are a lot of online tool for it.

Comment: A huge amount of code is written by complete amateurs. Wordpress is a cesspool of amateur code. Sadly, PHP is "easy" for such people to learn (to a point where they can produce something). Don't be surprised.

Comment: actually you can deobfuscate it if it doesn't use zend obfuscation. But you won't get pretty variable names mostly. But if you have something like eclipse with ctrl+alt+r renaming them to something usefull is done pretty quick.

Comment: I've just had a quick glance through the source, I don't see any obfuscation whatsoever. Can you post an example?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets, what you described is not de-obfuscate, but beautifier the obfuscated code and some people might confuse between obfuscated code and uglifier the code.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are enough red flags in your initial post for me to suggest steering well clear of it, to save yourself time/headaches in the long run.  And if it's obfuscated that means you can't even be sure what the code actually does (intentionally or otherwise), so it's a security risk.

Comment: WordPress is junk.  It's a horrid mess under the hood, and relies on a completely outdated programming model (The Loop... :shudder:).  And due to its ease of installation/use, it promotes a plugin environment filled with bad, even dangerous code.  If you're going to dabble in PHP, get a MVC framework like Symfony, do some research on Composer and the packages available on Packagist, and do it the right way.

Comment: @KevinM1 I feel like thats an apple and oranges comparison. Wordpress as a CMS can be extremely powerful and very intuitively set up for smaller clients without IT departments to manage their own websites. You're not forced to use these dangerous plugins. I'm curious why you think it's "a horrid mess under the hood."

Comment: @johnnyd23 - it's a factual state that Wordpress is a product of someone who had a good idea but no skills to execute the idea in such a way where security risks would be mitigated. In reality, WP's code is probably 3/10 and the fact that anyone can "extend" it and make a huge mess with their plugin is just bad. If you give WP to a non-technical people, they will install extensions and those extensions will come with problems - in the end, people do end up paying for other people to fix WP issues. Nothing is free, and IMO WP costs too much in the long run. I avoid it.

Comment: @johnnyd23 The Loop is a horrible mechanism, one that's nearly a decade outdated.  MVC is the de facto pattern of the web for a reason.  It's flexible, easy to maintain, easy to extend, etc.  WordPress also frequently uses globals, which are completely unnecessary in PHP's single threaded, fire-and-forget, no active memory environment.  Especially when all objects are passed by reference by default.  It is a widely used product masquerading as a professional product.  It is not.  For CMS', Drupal is better.  Joomla, from what I hear, is somewhat better.  There are likely other options, too.

Comment: @KevinM1 To each their own I suppose. I find Wordpress extremely practical as a CMS and far more intuitive for clients than Drupal or Joomla. That said, I develop my own themes and plugins so I cannot speak to the quality of websites others develop on the platform. Like any open source software it can be used for better or worse. One last thing I'll note is that within the past few years as its popularity as a CMS has increased i think it has improved dramatically - when was the last time you gave it an honest chance? Just food for thought. End rant.

Answer (score 1):

Just to hook in on your other question

> Is this common? I'm getting a bad feeling about PHP. Some of the code
>   I've seen just looks like it was written by amateurs.

No it's not common per se. But the fact of the matter is, php is a very very very messy language.
If you know what you are doing, know what pitfalls there are(0 == "0" == "" == false etc..) and how to account for them you are able to squeze something from it.

However, I would only advice php for really advanced people who know how code works and want to squeze a website or tool out.

The problem is, php is relatively easy to step into and to make it bend to your will, but it's extremely hard to master because of the gazillion quirks and pitfalls of PHP.

Just remember at all times: What am i doing, in what scope am I doing it and which variables am I using. Treat it like a C style application. Be memory concious, keep an eye on your scopes, types, etc...
Don't use the type switching feature if you don't have to.

Don't do

```
$x = 1;
$y = "2";
$z = $x+$y;
```

This makes you lazy. Use type casting and type checking to be sure what you are doing.

```
$x = 1;
$y = "2";
if(is_numeric($y)) {
    $tmp = (int)$y;
    $z = $x+$tmp;
}
else {
    throw new Exception("Err#0xDEAD Invalid argument provided.");
}
```

Why be so strict to yourself? It makes debugging a HELL OF A LOT easier in php.

So don't be put off by people who don't know how to code, PHP can be a fun tool, but never expect it to be perfect.

It's a tool. let's keep it at that.

Comment: Just to clarify, while many PHP developers are amateurs or largely unskilled; there are other PHP developers who are serious professionals, and believe in writing quality code as well

Comment: Yea, I agree. hence my comment for really advanced people. With that I mean people who know how references work, memory allocation, scoping, abstraction things like that. It's so easy to write a php script that eats up 60mb of ram whilst it would only need 500kb when optimised.